# java.nio.file.FileSystemException when I move a file

Tags: javafx, nio

I'm trying to move image files from beforePath to afterPath, and below is my Code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import static java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING;

public class ImageClass {
    String fileName, beforePath, afterPath;
    void moveFile() {
        afterPath = afterPath + "\\" + fileName;
        beforePath = beforePath + "\\" + fileName;
        System.out.println(beforePath + "  ,and,  " + afterPath);
        Path movefrom = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(beforePath);
        Path target = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(afterPath);

        try {
            Files.move(movefrom, target, REPLACE_EXISTING);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

however the code returns java.nio.file.FileSystemException to me and it says that another process is already using the file. I tried many ways but I can't. How can I fix it?

Comment: The most probable explanation is that another process is indeed using the file. There is nothing you can do about this, apart from closing the offending process.

Comment: Did you copy the code verbatim ? How do you set beforePath, fileName and afterPath ? I recommend that you try it with other files to see if it causes the same error.

Comment: It would be useful to paste in the full exception that you are seeing. It may be that the target directory doesn't exist (some of the Windows APIs returning non-obvious errors for cases like this).